# How to use closures of Jenkins Job DSL Plugin within groovy classes

Tags: groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm new to Job DSL Plugin and even Groovy.

Given the following script:

```
class MyClass {
    def create() {  
        folder('test') {
        }   
    }
}

new MyClass().create()
```

I'm getting the following error:

> javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptException: (script, line 3) No signature of method: MyClass.folder() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, MyClass$_create_closure1) values: [test, MyClass$_create_closure1@62591600]
>   Possible solutions: find(), collect()

Ok, clear. Groovy does not find a method called "folder" in my class. But this isn't a method. It is a Job DSL command. How can I use them within my classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the script reference into your class, see the [Job DSL wiki](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands#dsl-factory).

```
class MyClass {
    def create(def dslFactory) {  
        dslFactory.folder('test') {
        }   
    }
}

new MyClass().create(this)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Always difficult to find a solution if one doesn't know the keywords to google for...